# Custom filter: can I have custom buttons for filter?

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I am trying to have my own custom filter on [ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid) [angular](/questions/tagged/angular).
Apart from `Apply` button, I also want to have other buttons for the filter. i.e. if I can explain this in some sort of UI,

|--Custom Filter-------------------.
| Filter Text: _____________     |
| `Apply` | `Clear` | `Clear All`|
|_______________________|

By using default filter component of `ag-grid`, I know that I can have two buttons I need if I provide `filterParams` in `ColDef`.

```
filterParams: {
    applyButton: true,
    clearButton: true
}
```

But what about the other custom (`Clear All`) button? Is there any way I can achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achieved it after few hours of search and trial-error.

Have a look at the example given here: **[ag-Grid Angular Custom Filter Component](https://www.ag-grid.com/example-angular-filter/#gsc.tab=0)**
Have a look at the `PartialMatchFilterComponent` and its code.

After some code updates for template and component, we can achieve it.

Update the template:

```
<button (click)="apply()">Apply</button>
<button (click)="clear()">Clear</button>
<!-- any other buttons you want to keep -->
```

Little update in the component code: Just need to call `this.params.filterChangedCallback()` on `Apply` button click.

```
apply(): void {
    this.params.filterChangedCallback();
}
clear(): void {
    this.text = '';
    this.params.filterChangedCallback();
}
onChange(newValue): void {
    if (this.text !== newValue) {
        this.text = newValue;
        // this.params.filterChangedCallback(); - remove
    }
}
```

Comment: :sir i got filterChangedCallback undefined can you tell me why got undefined?